# How to show 2 different type of mappings between 2 entity classes, holding each other's reference

Tags: entity-framework, jpa, jakarta-ee

The mappings between the 2 tables(Department and Employee) is as follows (Link for the image showing mapping is also provided):

- Every department has one and only one department head.
- Every department can have more than one employee.
- dept_id and empId are primary keys of their respective tables.
- dept_head(It is the Employee Id) and dept are foreign keys of their
  respective tables.

[Mapping Employee and Department table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDhoa.jpg)

I created entity classes for the above 2 tables (The structure is provided below).

**Employee Class:**

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "empId")
private Integer empId;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "address")
private String address;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "grade")
private String grade;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@JoinColumn(name = "dept", referencedColumnName = "dept_id")
@ManyToOne
private Department deptartment; 
.. ... 
}
```

**Department class:**

```
public class Department implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 8)
@Column(name = "dept_id")
private String deptId;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@JoinColumn(name = "dept_head", referencedColumnName = "empId")
@OneToOne
private Employee deptHead;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "deptartment")
private List<Employee> employeeList;
....
...
}
```

If I am adding mappedBy in Employee Class (like I did in Department), to show OneToOne mapping between empId and deptHead,the code is compiling and running. However, If I do not add the mappedBy statement in Employee class, as the above code shows, the code still compiles and runs fine.

I would want to know why the code above works even if I am not providing mappedBy in employee class.

If anybody can help me clearing the above doubts and explaining the logic behind its working would be great as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear where you tried to user it with and without the `mappedBy` attribute.

But if I get your question correctly, you ask why you can have only one or both sides annotated?

It depends on which side is the source and destination of your relation or wheter it's bi-directional. On the Java-side you can have a relation always in both directions due to object references, but on the Database-side, you might only have it in one direction.

Check out [JPA Wiki book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne) on that topic for more details.

Additionally, the API doc for `OneToOne` states:

> Specifies a single-valued association to another entity that has
>   one-to-one multiplicity. It is not normally necessary to specify the
>   associated target entity explicitly since it can usually be inferred
>   from the type of the object being referenced. If the relationship is
>   bidirectional, the non-owning side must use the mappedBy element of
>   the OneToOne annotation to specify the relationship field or property
>   of the owning side.